# Introducir un input en html para una verificación

Tags: html, css, input

me gustaría introducir un input en mi formulario, para verificacion, el caso es que no doy con el elemento html para darle este estilo, me refiero concretamente, a un input que dentro del mismo tenga subdivisiones entre dígitos

Comment: Si no es con javascript dudo que puedas hacerlo como planeas. Con HTML solo se me ocurre que uses el atributo **placeholder** para mostrar el formato deseado cuando el campo está aún vacío y el atributo **pattern** para que el contenido del campo sea validado con el formato deseado al darle al submit del formulario.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado con el tag select?, échale un vistazo https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

```html
<label for="digit">Elige el dígito:</label>
    
<select name="cars" id="cars">
<option value="digit1">1</option>
<option value="digit2">2</option>
<option value="digit3">3</option>
<option value="digit4">4</option>
</select>
```